# Using ffmpeg showwaves as circle. Is it possible?

Tags: ffmpeg

Showwaves are normally used in a horizontal manner.
Is it possible to display the waveform in a circle?

Something like this?

[image]

Comment: Not without some sort of bad looking raster distortion.

Comment: I'd probably use after effects for this, but I would take a long time because I forgot how to use it.